# Perfect forwarding constructor and inheriting constructors

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer, perfect-forwarding

Given this class hierarchy:

```
#include <iostream>

class Base {
public:
    Base() = default;
    Base(const Base&) { std::cout << "  copy\n"; }
    
    template<typename T>
    Base(T&&) { std::cout << "  T&&\n"; }
};

class Sub : public Base {
public:
    using Base::Base;
};
```

It [is known](https://mpark.github.io/programming/2014/06/07/beware-of-perfect-forwarding-constructors/) that this code would print `T&&`:

```
// objects
Base varObj;
const Base constObj;
// invoking constructors
Base copy(varObj);              // T&&
Base move(std::move(constObj)); // T&&
Base number(42);                // T&&
```

Why does using `Sub` instead of `Base` "fix" the problem?

```
// objects
Sub varObj;
const Sub constObj;
// invoking constructors
Sub copy(varObj);              // copy
Sub move(std::move(constObj)); // copy
Sub number(42);                // T&&
```

Comment: fyi commenting out `using Base::Base;` and I get compiler differences between cland and gcc - live - https://godbolt.org/z/WMG5xTodz

Comment: Moving a const object is a bad practice. As the source object is constant, it cannot be modified, so you will get a copy and it make the code misleading.

Comment: @RichardCritten, interesting that `Sub number(42);` then invokes the `T&&` constructor twice. However, this happens only with `-std=c++20`. With C++17 GCC generates the same error as Clang does. It looks like a regression introduced by GCC 10.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is [CWG2356](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#2356): the inherited constructor is **still** a better match for a non-const input (because of the qualification conversion required), but it is discarded by [over.match.funcs]/8.  Part of the reason for this is to avoid making any class that inherits constructors implicitly convertible from its base class.

There is still the possibility that the `Sub` copy constructor (used by both of your initializations) would invoke the constructor template.  However, its source parameter is a `const Sub&`, so its base subobject is a `const Base&`.  That’s an **exact** match for the `Base` copy constructor, so it’s selected over the template (which otherwise wins because of qualification conversions or reference kind).

Comment: I think the question is not why `Sub` copy ctor calls `Base` copy ctor. It's about why `Sub` copy ctor is preferred over the inherited template ctor to begin with.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: That's a valid point.  I was imagining some sort of hiding that doesn't happen here.  I extended the answer significantly.